# React-redux: Trouble triggering child component action on parent state change

Tags: react-redux

I am passing a galleryReload prop to DisplayImages from UploadImages to re fetch a list of files after a new file is uploaded.

I am having trouble getting DisplayImages to run it's getImages action on the state change of the parent without causing an endless loop.

```
class UploadImage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      galleryReload: false
    };
...
// in render
<DisplayImages galleryReload={this.state.galleryReload} />
```

In DisplayImages I can get first display of images with:

```
//works fine on first load 
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getImages(this.props.gallery);
    }
  }
```

I am really having trouble figuring out how to run the action  this.props.getImages(this.props.gallery) again after a file has been uploaded.

I tried setting the state of {galleryReload: true} once upload was finished (in parent) like so:

```
//onUploadFinished
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  galleryReload: true
}));
```

and fetching the results again in child with componentWillUpdate and other lifecycle methods, but I kept getting myself into an endless loop of fetching.

Here is an example of what I put into the various lifecycle methods to fetch and then stop further fetches until the next upload completes:

```
  if (this.props.galleryReload) {
      this.props.getImages(this.props.gallery);
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        galleryReload: false
      }));
    }
```

How do I rework this to call getImages just one time after image upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that in learning react and redux at the same time I was confusing state.  I was not setting redux state in parent, but rather local state.  So to reset the local state of parent component from child component I needed to use a callback function in parent that sets the state of galleryReload and pass it as prop to child component.

In my parent I added the function:

```
  resetGalleryReload() {
    this.setState({
      galleryReload: false
    });
  }
```

I also set in parent constructor

```
this.resetGalleryReload = this.resetGalleryReload.bind(this);
```

Then I sent to child component as prop like so

```
    <DisplayImages
      galleryReload={this.state.galleryReload}
      resetReloadGallery={this.resetGalleryReload}
    />
```

Finally, I educated myself on the use of lifecycle methods with this nice read:
https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/introduction.html

So I created this in DisplayImages component

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let val = this.props.galleryReload;
    if (val) {
      this.props.getImages(this.props.gallery);
      this.props.resetReloadGallery();
    }
  }
```

I